# nestedScrollView is stretching imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview

i'm trying to nest a imageview inside a linearlayout inside a nestedscrollview.. But the nestedscrollview is stretching the imageview and I can't seem to find the error:

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llImageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivNewProductBarcode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_barcode_image"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llRest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivDateIconView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/etProductName"
                        android:background="@color/card_background"
                        android:contentDescription="ImageView for icon: Date" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etProductName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:hint="Name" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                        android:hint="Type" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/llImageview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_new_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:title="@string/newproducttitle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And a image of how it looks on the phone:
[image: Image Stretched]
[image: Image Stretched and rest of gui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:**

I ended up recoding the entire layout file, and updated my Gradle module file, so that the design libs is now in 23.3.0.. That somehow fixed the problem. For others who run into the same problem, here is my layout code, and Gradle scripts:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coAddNewProductContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_barcode_image" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDatePick"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:text="Date to pick" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvDatePick"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:hint="@string/testingString" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/etName"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:hint="@string/app_name" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etName" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/llImageView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_new_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
...
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llImageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivNewProductBarcode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llRest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivDateIconView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/etProductName"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:contentDescription="ImageView for icon: Date" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etProductName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:hint="Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:hint="Type" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/llImageview"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_new_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:title="product"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Just updated my question, but that did unfortunately not solve my problem.. :/ But thanks for trying

Comment: Updated my answer try @Lasse